# Hide helper text box from xterm js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xtermjs

I am using the xterm js to create a terminal application. When I add it to my Angular app, it shows the basic terminal but also a textbox with "W" on top of it.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let term = new Terminal();
    let fitAddon = new FitAddon();
    term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
    let element = document.getElementById('terminal');
    if (element) {
      term.open(element);
      fitAddon.fit();
      term.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mvXterm\x1B[0m $ ');
      term.onKey((key) => {
        console.log(key);
        if (key.domEvent.code === 'Enter') {
          term.writeln('');
          term.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31xTerm\x1B[0m $ ');
        } else {
          term.write(key.key);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

and terminal.component.html file:

```
<div class="terminal" id="terminal"></div>
```

[image: xterm]

When I click on the terminal, the cursor appears on the textbox and it is DOM element from the library. Does anyone know how to remove or hide it?[image]

Comment: Is it always a "W"? Or are you pressing the "W" key? Can you please provide the HTML as well? Only the part where the `terminal` element is.

Comment: it's always there, and my html is very short, just one line

Comment: copy of this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180685/xterm-js-how-to-hide-xterm-helper-textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is from my testing environment. not the library. Closing the question

Comment: And you could just use a css selector to highlight that helper class and add display: none property that way it isn’t showing in your development environment. Or you could use javascript to remove it completely when the page loads. $(“.className”).removeNode. Keep in mind that is pseudo code for the selector and may not be the correct syntax