# Xterm.js: How to hide xterm-helper-textarea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xtermjs

I try to use Xtermjs in Reactjs. but when I follow the guide. the result shows as following:

[image]

**It should show without top textarea and text 'W'.**

My codes is as following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import { FitAddon } from 'xterm-addon-fit'; 

class XTerminal extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const {id} = this.props;
        const terminalContainer = document.getElementById(id);
        const terminal = new Terminal({cursorBlink: true});
        const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
        terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
        terminal.open(terminalContainer);
        terminal.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ');
        fitAddon.fit();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={this.props.id}></div>
        )
    }
}

export default XTerminal;
```

I seach a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886813/hide-helper-text-box-from-xterm-js) without no answer. and I cannot comment in that question. So I write this question. Could anyone help? thanks :)

Comment: how is it supposed to look?

Comment: it should show without top textarea and text 'W',@ChristianFritz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I got this. For those who have this problem. you should import [xterm css style file](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/master/css/xterm.css). like following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import './xterm.css';
import { FitAddon } from 'xterm-addon-fit'; 

class XTerminal extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const {id} = this.props;
        const terminalContainer = document.getElementById(id);
        const terminal = new Terminal({cursorBlink: true});
        const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
        terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
        terminal.open(terminalContainer);
        terminal.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ');
        fitAddon.fit();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={this.props.id}></div>
        )
    }
}

export default XTerminal;
```